# Maths of chords

Tags: reference-request, music-theory

I have a few naive questions on music theory. Let us assume that I have two pitches A and C with certain frequencies. Then the corresponding sound waves are pure sinusoidal waves. But what happens if I vibrate the chord A-C? To get the resulting wave, I should simply sum up mathematically the corresponding sin waves? Conversely, if someone gives me a wave, how can I say that is, for instance, an A-C chord?

Any remarks welcomed...

Comment: What do you mean exactly with "$A-C$ chord" ? Playing the two pitches in the same time ?

Comment: Yes, playing the two pitches at the same time.

Comment: So adding the two sinusoids... The (discrete) Fourier transform lets us write a signal as a sum of sinusoids. It is unperfect (thus complicated to use for sums of many - possibly time-varying- sinusoids) because the signal is finite and sampled.

Comment: This does not sound like a math question.  Maybe you have a better luck consulting physicists, or even engineers.  People who work on music transcription may be able to answer the question better.

Comment: If you are going to try to apply this to music, you should keep in mind that if you play an A on a musical instrument, you don't get a pure sine wave, because you also get harmonics (overtones). Which ones you get, and with what amplitudes, will depend on the instrument.

Comment: Thank you. I am just looking for some oversimplified math model to grab the phenomena.

Comment: Crossposted to https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/372760/2451